# Broken jobs, triggers or packages alert

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers, package, jobs

Sometimes, once or twice a year, I find broken jobs, triggers or packages in my oracle database, to fix it is not a problem but the headache it causes grow exponentially each minute it is broken.

My question is simple, is that a way to have an alert every time a job, trigger or packages alert is broken?

Anything from a email (best solution) to some data written in a table.

Thanks in advance

Comment: There's quite a big difference between a broken job, vs. an invalid trigger or package. Triggers and packages are automatically recompiled when they are first run, so (assuming they compile without errors) you don't have to worry about them.

Comment: It runs for months without problem, until one day I need to manually go there and recompile without any apparent reason.

Comment: Why do you think you need to recompile them?

Comment: Because in Toad show a red cross on top and the packages, triggers, jobs, do not work until I recompile it. Once recompiled all works fine. Ps. jobs are a bit different they go off line.

Comment: The red mark simply means it's been marked invalid, which in itself does not necessarily require you to recompile.

Comment: Try an experiment: leave them invalid, and see if anything stops working.

Comment: No need to experiment, I know it stop to work because my clients start to call as they entries are not been processed. After recompile all start to work again

Comment: You need to determine what the cause of the invalidations is, and what is stopping the entries to not be "processed". The invalidations are a symptom of an underlying issue. You should not normally need to always recompile all the time in an Oracle system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends somewhat on what you mean exactly by "broken", but if you mean that the code has been invalidated:

```
SELECT object_type, object_name FROM user_objects WHERE status = 'INVALID'
```

or use `dba_objects` if you have access to it and want to check all schemas at once.

Comment: Thanks @Dave Costa that works, I add as a batch file that sent an email as soon as it happens and now I can relax. Ps. By broken I mean some jobs just go off-line without reason and some triggers and packages need recompiling for no apparent reason too.